# Where do you put responsive mixins in Bootstrap 4 SCSS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, sass, bootstrap-4

Where do you put responsive mixins in Bootstrap 4? SCSS  I tried in _custom.scss and mixins.scss but des not work. I'm using the provided mixins by Bootstrap 4 like,

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .some-class {
display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new master SCSS file where you import Bootstrap 4 first, and then your styles, like:

```
@import "path/to/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "path/to/custom/scss/custom";
```

This way you can use Bootstrap mixins in your `custom.scss` (or `_custom.scss`).

(Or you can put your SCSS rules directly in this file instead of the 2nd import, if you wish.)

Then just include the CSS result of this master file in your website.